# Disable opposite input if I type into another of a pair

Tags: javascript, jquery, disabled-input, prop

How do I disable one input field if I type into another out of a pair and then if I removed the input by hitting backspace for example so there is nothing in the input field reenable the second input field and vice versa. Code I have so far is below but is not working.

JavaScript:

```
    //disable the opposite input field
    var ATGvalue = $('input#atgOrderId').val();
    var BQvalue = $('input#bqOrderId').val();

    if ( ATGvalue.length > 0) {
        $('input#bqOrderId').prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $('input#bqOrderId').removeAttr("disabled");
    }

    if ( BQvalue.length > 0) {
        $('input#atgOrderId').prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $('input#atgOrderId').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
```

HTML:

```
<label for="bqOrderId">bqOrderId </label><input name="bqOrderId" id="bqOrderId" type="text" />
<label for="atgOrderId">atgOrderId </label><input name="atgOrderId" id="atgOrderId" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does work, but only once - to have it continuously update, you first wrap the JS in an event-handler function and attach it to your input elements:

```
function mutuallyExclusive( e ) { ... }
$( '#bqOrderId' ).on( 'change keyup', mutuallyExclusive );
$( '#atgOrderId' ).on( 'change keyup', mutuallyExclusive );
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aP3Hn/1/).

I attached it to both the `change` and `keyup` events: `change` to handle programatic (scripted) changes, and `keyup` to "instantly" update the fields' statuses - otherwise it waits till the user removes focus from the input to call the `change` event.

Answer (score 0):

you need to include your code inside an event to check when a user type something like this:

```
$(document).on('keyup','#bqOrderId',function(){
   //your code
});

$(document).on('keyup','#atgOrderId',function(){
  //your code
});
```

after to change this:

```
$('input#bqOrderId').prop("disabled", true);
$('input#atgOrderId').prop("disabled", true);
```

to this:

```
$('input#bqOrderId').attr("disabled",true);
$('input#atgOrderId').attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: This works but it only runs on first load of the page. I need it to look at the length of these values continuously.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try changing the following line

`$('input#atgOrderId').removeAttr("disabled");`
with this: `$('input#atgOrderId').removeProp("disabled");`

Hope this helps